# keep my app waiting for phone calls

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have an android app which waits for incoming calls to arrive and then (when the call state changes (I'm using the telephony manager class to detect incoming calls and its working great)) my app does something.
The problem is, if my app is running and listening for calls in the background, and then I open some other heavy apps and using them massively, my app gets paused by the system and the user must re-open it in order to resume listening for phone calls.
Is there a way to keep my app waiting for calls as long as the user didn't press on the "stop listening" button inside my app ? 
Thanks.

Comment: What for ? I think it's very common that apps get closed when they aren't being used after some time, and the user is using some other apps instead. That's my case.

Comment: Than you have your answer...

Comment: Imagine an app with a timer. The timer is set to tick in an hour. But the user is  using some other apps, and then suddenly my app gets suspended, which means the timer might not tick at all cause the whole app is suspended. What you're saying is that no one ever have found a solution to create such timer. All I m looking for is some theoretic solution to this problem. Some guidance. Thanks

Comment: By the way...I see I m getting too many downvotes. I'll be glad if one of you Will explain what is so wrong with my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this wil help you ,i had the same thing and i solved it with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672031/recording-calls-in-android-why-this-not-works) answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `Broadcast Receiver` to receive telephony broadcasts, which you have to register in a background `Service`. This way, the system will automatically notify your app about the events and also restart the app if it's not already running (of course, it won't happen if the app was force closed).