# How to record voice call using AudioSource.VOICE_CALL

Tags: android, recorder

trying to record call, I am using `MediaRecorder class` when using `AudioSource.MIC` or `AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION` its recording only my voice not from recevier
and when I use `AudioSource.VOICE_CALL` it gives exception on attending call..
here is code

```
if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")){
            if((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null){
                state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                    inCall = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                    wasRinging = true;
                    Toast.makeText(context, inCall + " is calling", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                    if(wasRinging){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Call Answered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Date date = new Date();
                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss");

                        String filename = "rec_" + format.format(date) + ".mp3";
                        String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).getPath();
                        String fileUri = path + "/" + filename;
                        Log.v("testing uri", fileUri);
                        File file = new File(fileUri);

                        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
                        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
                        recorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

                        try {
                            recorder.prepare();
                            recorder.start();
                            recording = true;

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                    wasRinging = false;
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if(recording && recorder != null){
                        recorder.stop();
                        recorder = null;
                        recording = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And this is error..

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.asadullah.callrecorder.MyBroadCastReceiver@41d6c7a8
   at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:778)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
   at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
   at com.asadullah.callrecorder.MyBroadCastReceiver.onReceive(MyBroadCastReceiver.java:62)
   at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:768)
```

manifests permissions are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 4):

`VOICE_CALL` is deprecated now. That is why this error occurred.

Use `VOICE_COMMUNICATION` as AudioSource as it is microphone audio source tuned for voice communications such as VoIP.

I am also working with call recording app but it failed in Android 7.1.1

If you are not trying call record on Android 7.1.1 below code will work.

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

Comment: will your suggested code record mic as well as speaker voice too? means all two way voices?

Comment: yes my suggestion is worked for me besides 7.1.1, try this one this will be worked for you. if you cannot hear voice from receiver using VOICE_COMMUNICATION try MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT as well.

Comment: Thank you . You saved my ass.

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda hi i tried all the way bro, still not able to get the result for recording. can you help me to solve my issue?

Comment: I have tried recording call using `VOICE_COMMUNICATION` but it only records from mic not the sound coming from speaker. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

In order to use VOICE_CALL you need to take special permission.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT"
   tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

Comment: How do you take this special permission? Is it really possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think you require some permissions before recording in newer version of android (Api 23).
Check out this SO question - [Recording calls in android why this not works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672031/recording-calls-in-android-why-this-not-works)

**Permissions**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

And if you require more help you can even check official [document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder.html) for more info regarding this error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to take this permission.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: How can you get this permission exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You need the CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT permission for Voice_Call, which [is documented here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html).

But you will NOT get the permission for the reason [stated here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT).

Note the line "**Not for use by third-party applications.**"

Comment: So how could it help to add it, if you can't have it granted?

Comment: If your app is not a third party app.

Comment: Is it possible, using root, to have this permission?

Comment: I believe so, however, I a not sure how.

Comment: I guess you add your app as a system app and then do the request as normal for capture_audio_output and voice_call which you should then be granted.

Comment: I've tried it, but it doesn't seem to really grant it. Doesn't even return that it was granted.

Comment: I am no expert on this at all, however it is is something like; root device, generate certificate for the app, add the certificate into the folder for system layer certificates, sign the app with the certificate and then install - it should then be get the permissions.

Comment: I don't know how to do it using root. Can you please show in code?

Comment: I am sorry nor do I, I have not done it before and the above is a theoretical approach. You could try https://www.androidauthority.com/install-user-app-as-system-app-how-to-93522/

Comment: Is it just on my web browser, or does it have weird lines of code there, of "CPP" , "exit" , as well as bullets ?